# Interpreting permissions from the Confluence REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I can get a list of permissions from the Confluence REST API (using PythonConfluenceAPI):

```
p = api.get_space_information(space_key, expand="permissions")['permissions']
```

I get a list of dictionaries, with information about operations and subjects.  But there are mismatches between the information from the API, and the permissions displayed in Confluence:

- There are operations in the API that are not in the browser (update blogpost).
- There are operations in the browser that are not in the API (space export, space admin, mail delete).
- There are entries in the API list that have no operation specified at all, and these entries often duplicated appear multiple times.

What I really want to get is a list of space admins. I'm hoping someone can explain these permission structures the API is giving me.

Answer (score 3):

Like you I wasn't able to use the RPC api that seemed to have been removed entirely. There is a few things you can use if you want to grab a list of the space admins.

The simple way would be to use the `/rest/api/group/confluence-administrators/member` route, that will return you the list of all the members of the confluence administrators that would automatically be space admins.

If you don't have a lot of users, you could also use the [Space Permissions Handler add-on](https://github.com/ttorvela/space-permissions-handler) that you can install on the administration panel. It will provide you an api with all the permissions of a given user, with the same type of format that were returned by the old `getSpacePermissionSets`.

[image: api debug]

But still it might be a pain and not the most helpful thing if you have a lot of users to check them individually. I created a Confluence add-on that would allow me to use the java api, and leverage the [getAdmins](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/5.8.9/com/atlassian/confluence/plugins/spacedirectory/rest/SpaceDirectoryEntity.html#getAdmins--) method of the SpaceDirectoryEntity.

The single endpoint is pretty straightforward:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{key}")
public Response getAdmins(@PathParam("key") String key) {
  Space space = spaceManager.getSpace(key);
  if (space == null) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
  }

  List<User> admins = spaceManager.getSpaceAdmins(space);
  List<Object> out = new ArrayList<Object>();

  for (User admin: admins) {
      Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
      item.put("fullName", admin.getFullName());
      item.put("name", admin.getName());
      item.put("email", admin.getEmail());
      out.add(item);
  }

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(out);
  return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```

And would give this kind of response if given a valid space key:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "admin",
    "fullName": "admin",
    "email": "admin@hehe.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "admin2",
    "fullName": "admin2",
    "email": "admin2@hehe.com"
  }
]
```

Might need a little more work to cleanup the add-on if you want me to open-source it, just tell me if you would be interested.

Comment: @Nedatchelder Tell me if I'm missing anything

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no proper documentation across the REST API and the way that you can get the Space Admin Permission via this. However, I believe you are able to use the old **JSON-RPC API** to get the list of the space permissions. It's accessible via:

```
http://<confluence-url>/rpc/json-rpc/confluenceservice-v2/getSpacePermissionSets
```

It technically returns the response like following:

```
[
  {
    "type": "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "VIEWSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EDITBLOG",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EDITSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "COMMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you don't have any limitation and you are able to run the query against the database, you can also use following Query:

```
SELECT s.SPACENAME, u.username FROM SPACES s 
 JOIN SPACEPERMISSIONS p ON s.SPACEID = p.SPACEID
 JOIN user_mapping u ON p.PERMUSERNAME = u.user_key 
  WHERE p.PERMTYPE = 'SETSPACEPERMISSIONS';
```

Above query returns the list of the space administrators for all spaces across your instance.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble finding examples of using Python to access the JSON-RPC API.  I get 404's when I try posting with requests.  Should it be available on my wiki? https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OXA/Open+edX+Answers

Comment: ahhh you are on Atlassian Cloud I don't think SOAP is available for Cloud version. Well, check this REST API then and see if it suits (https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#space-space) . Note that, if you just need it for one time, may be you can check with Atlassian Support to see if they can run that query for you or not :-)

Comment: That REST API is where I started, and where I am getting strange half-populated permissions lists... Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries Ned. Wish I could help but unfortunately, API doc is still not complete and no enough resource for it specially for Cloud with all restrictions.